# readFile returning different Buffer value every time

Tags: javascript, node.js

My application produces thumbnails from Highcharts to display on a UI. Every time, I refresh the page, the order of the thumbnails changes.

After some investigation, I found that `data` is a different buffer value every time (even **before** I pass it into the base64 conversion function) which is causing my `fileImageArray` to be in a different order every time as well.

I am passing the correct `files[i]` into `readFile` every time so that is not the error.

This is my function to read files:

```
function getFiles(callback) {
    var filesNameArray = [], fileImageArray = [], base64 = "";
    fs.readdir(graphDir, function(err, files) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            for (var i in files) {
                filesNameArray.push(files[i].substr(0, files[i].indexOf(".")));
                fs.readFile(graphDir + files[i], function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        base64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' + conversions.bufferToBase64(data);
                        fileImageArray.push(base64);
                    }
                });
            }
            callback(filesNameArray, fileImageArray);
        }
    });
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What system are you running the code on? As the behavior differs in linux and windows.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a known issue with node's `fs` implementation.
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3232

I would suggest you either try `fs.readdirSync` if you can afford the blocking IO. Or sort the array of files in the callback like this.

```
fs.readdir(graphDir, function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {

        // sort files
        files = files.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a < b ? -1 : 1;
        });

        for (var i in files) {
            filesNameArray.push(files[i].substr(0, files[i].indexOf(".")));
            fs.readFile(graphDir + files[i], function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    base64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' + conversions.bufferToBase64(data);
                    fileImageArray.push(base64);
                }
            });
        }
        callback(filesNameArray, fileImageArray);
    }
});
```

I would also suggest that you switch your `for` loop to `.forEach` for optimized behavior.

Comment: `readdirSync` slowed the application down considerably so I don't think I can do that. Sorting the files made not change at all as it is not the files that are the problem. Like I said in my question, I seem to be passing in the correct file name every time but seems to give a different output

Comment: Here is what I suspect, the `.readdir` callback returns files in a different sequence everytime. It is less likely for `.readFile` to return an incorrect file. What is likely is that some other logic is writing incorrect files OR the change in sequence leads to what you believe as incorrect files. Possible?

Comment: That is possible yes but I still don't understand (as I placed checks everywhere) that the correct file name seemed to be going into `readFile` but the wrong content coming out